# Connecting 5V PSU to GPIO

Tags: gpio, alternative-power

Disclaimer: My knowledge is fairly limited when it comes to electronics.

I want to connect an external PSU to the 2/4 GPIO pins.
[Link to PSU](http://www.mouser.com/search/ProductDetail.aspx?r=709-GST25A05-P1J)

I didn't know a barrel to microUSB adaptor exist and I cut off the connector, so I now have 2 exposed wires coming out of the PSU.
I want to know what the best way would be to physically connect these to the pins?

I wanted to use Dupont connectors but the wires are 16AWG and I'm not sure they will fit (and I don't have any around to try)

Are there any other suggested ways to connect directly to the pins or to "break-out" the pins just for this purpose?

Thanks!

Note: I know that connecting directly to the GPIO will bypass the builtin protection mechanisms. The PSU is 5V regulated (5%). I am not sure if this counts as a comprehensive test but I measured it with the MinMax function of my Fluke Min==Max==Avg==5.135V

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jumper wire with a female end.  Just cut it in half and solder or twist the +5v power wire to the jumper wire and insulate with tape.  Ditto for the ground wire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking of doing this as well. I have some heatshrink so can use that for insulation

Comment: What! No **GPIO** disclaimer?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Pi question, however I feel obliged to comment.

There is nothing wrong with connecting to the power pins on the header, see [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) **HOWEVER** I would not use Dupont connectors.

You will be connecting these hundreds of times. It is only a matter of time before you do it wrong. Use of an unpolarised connector is inherently risky.

When I need to use an external supply I usually do one of 2 things;

1. Obtain a USB to microUSB adapter (these are readily available on ebay) and solder a normal male USB cable to the PSU, **TRIPLE** checking polarity before connecting to the Pi.
2. Use a female USB connector wired to the PSU and a normal microUSB power cable.